# Struggling with creating extension for Button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been trying to make an extension that would change how a button is created, but with no luck.

The usual way of making a button would be like this:

```
Button {
    print("pressed")
} label: {
    Label("Button", systemImage: "person")
}
```

However I would like to be able to create buttons like this:

```
Button("Button", systemImage: "person") {
    print("pressed")
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am sure you have tried something. Can you show that code? What part of it doesn't work?

Comment: @loremipsum I have tried, although the code is full of errors. I don't think I know what I'm doing. Should I add it to the question anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main non-obvious part in this issue is to confirm and align generics of new custom `init` in extension with one used in SwiftUI `Button`, because of used same name `Label` for different things.

Here is a main part of found solution:

```
init(_ title: LocalizedStringKey, systemImage: String, action: @escaping () -> Void) 
     where Label == SwiftUI.Label<Text, Image> {
```

Complete [findings and solution is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Extension_Button_Custom_Init.md)